# Set <div> element to fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element `<div class="stock-list-head"></div>`. This element contains titles for list of products (Article Number, Article Name, Price...).

So, I want this `div` to be fixed while scrolling products (Actually, products have to go behind the `<div>` while scrolling).

I tried with jquery function that catches scroll event:

```
 $( document ).scroll(function(){
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     if(scroll>1){
         $(".stock-list-head").css("position", "fixed");
         $(".stock-list-head").css("top", "10px");
         $(".stock-list-head").css("marginTop", "-101px");
         // And some similar styles but without success.
     }
}
```

All the time, the div is going down for 50px and is getting fixed in there.

Comment: can you post a fiddle of your html, jquery & css code? I dont quite get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Have z-index value greater than the products for the div.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/byVTANix

Comment: can you try to reproduce your problem on a working example? [Here is a fiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/L7w69nmy/), I just set a big size to the page height to be able to scroll. You can see the fixed div doesn't move..

Answer (score 2):

This should fix the problem:

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 56px;
}

header {
  overflow: auto;
}

header,
#header-fix {
  display: block;
  height: 56px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #5b27ad;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

header.fixed {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

div.fixed {
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<header class="fixed">
  <h2>Logo here</h2>
</header>
<div id="header-fix" class="fixed"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Also, you can use another method (but it may be poor in some cases) - add CSS

```
body {
    margin-top: <here header height>; /* you can check height with devtools */
}
```

or use `padding-top`

Comment: I have     
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999; and using margins positioned the div properly.
But, when I am scrolling down, the <div> goes down for some pixels (ex.50px down) and then it's fixing there.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted!
Thank you a lot!

Comment: you added a kitten for our judgement not to be objective and upvote.. well that's unfair but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```js
$( document ).scroll(function(){
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     if(scroll>1){
         $(".stock-list-head").css("position", "fixed");
         $(".stock-list-head").css("top", "0px");
         // And some similar styles but without success.
     }else if(scroll == 0){
     $(".stock-list-head").css("position", "relative");
      $(".stock-list-head").css("top", "0px");
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="stock-list-head">
  <h4>Header</h4>
</header>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div>
```

Comment: With using your code I am in the same situation from the images attached above.